# Android emulator Mac OSX hangs on screen showing 'ANDROID_'

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, emulation

I have read many cases of the Android emulator not loading up and I am trying to determine if there are any solutions yet.

`Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...` is the last item logged in the eclipse console and the following logging repeats in what appears to be an infinite loop in the `Logcat` on the DDMS perspective...

```
04-17 00:11:29.431: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2525): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
04-17 00:11:29.431: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2525): CheckJNI is ON
04-17 00:11:29.551: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2525): --- registering native functions ---
04-17 00:11:29.581: WARN/dalvikvm(2525): ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Landroid/view/KeyCharacterMap;.get_native (III)C
04-17 00:11:29.581: WARN/dalvikvm(2525): ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Landroid/view/KeyCharacterMap;.getNumber_native (II)C
04-17 00:11:29.591: WARN/dalvikvm(2525): ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Landroid/view/KeyCharacterMap;.getMatch_native (II[CI)C
04-17 00:11:29.591: WARN/dalvikvm(2525): ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Landroid/view/KeyCharacterMap;.getDisplayLabel_native (II)C
04-17 00:11:29.591: WARN/dalvikvm(2525): ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Landroid/view/KeyCharacterMap;.getKeyData_native (IILandroid/view/KeyCharacterMap$KeyData;)Z
04-17 00:11:29.591: WARN/dalvikvm(2525): ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Landroid/view/KeyCharacterMap;.getKeyboardType_native (I)I
04-17 00:11:29.591: WARN/dalvikvm(2525): ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Landroid/view/KeyCharacterMap;.getEvents_native (I[C)[J
04-17 00:11:29.591: ERROR/JNIHelp(2525): RegisterNatives failed for 'android/view/KeyCharacterMap'
04-17 00:11:29.591: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2525): Unable to register all android natives
04-17 00:11:29.612: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
04-17 00:11:29.612: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'media.player' died
04-17 00:11:29.612: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'media.camera' died
04-17 00:11:29.612: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'media.audio_policy' died
04-17 00:11:30.081: INFO/(2526): ServiceManager: 0xacd0
04-17 00:11:30.081: DEBUG/AudioHardwareInterface(2526): setMode(NORMAL)
04-17 00:11:30.081: INFO/CameraService(2526): CameraService started: pid=2526
04-17 00:11:30.081: INFO/AudioFlinger(2526): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb3f0 ready to run
```

It is not clear to me what I can do to make this work, as everything I have tried so far has not worked including:

1. Making the 32 bit Java default
2. Adding the -d32 parameter to the DDMS file in the tools directory of the android install location.
3. Running the emulator from the terminal

None of these have seemed to make any difference.

Please let me know if there is anything obvious I have missed or solutions I have not tried yet.

Comment: How long have you waited?  Peoples' patience often wears out before the emulator gets fully launched.  You'd be surprised at how long it can take.

Comment: As a frame of reference this is a brand new MacBookPro with a quad core i7 and 8 gig of ram. The longest I waited was to let the emulator sit in the hung state overnight in attempts to see what might happen with nothing. I have tried several restarts of the computer eclipse adb and several combinations over the past week as I have read in many places the emulator can be very slow to start up..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the "android" tool to delete the avd and recreating it? It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

After three months of experimenting I finally got one to work by selecting `Marshmallow ARM EABA v7a` in `Other Images` tab in Android Studio's Virtual Device Configuration.

`Tools` > `Android` > `AVD Manager`> `+ Create Virtual Device`> `Choose Device` > `Next` > `Other Images`

[image]

Comment: You do realize the marshmallow image did not exist when this post was created, yes?

Comment: Why does that matter? Will this question only be read by people from the past? :)

Comment: No, just saying that your answer likely is unrelated to the solution that was needed 5 years ago :)

Comment: True :D Although armeabi-v7a existed then (I think) so if Doctor Who goes back to see OP it might help him then as much as it did me today.